# Jquery delayed RSS feed replaces all html in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rss

My pages are loading very slowly. It's because I have an external RSS feed being fed into the page, which takes a while to load. If I could delay this I wouldn't mind as all the other content would have loaded. I've tried the following to a strange end:

```
    setTimeout(function() {
    var feed = $.get('http://feed.informer.com/widgets/BYDE3BCLGN.js');
    $('#cc-news div').load(feed);
}, 3000);
```

What happens is that after the three second delay all the HTML inside the body tag gets replace by the linked code, so I'm just looking at a white screen with text.

I've tried a couple of different things but I'm not adept at jquery, and have found no solutions online so I need a little help, any would be much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to register an *ajax callback event* - see this:

http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/